# Calculating MASE Scores for Individual Participants

Tags: forecasting, measurement-error, mase

I have run a controlled experiment in which 30 participants made one step ahead forecasts under two separate conditions. I want to know if there is a difference in error scores between the two conditions. Each participant makes 15 seperate forecasts.

In line with the formula for [MASE](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/foresight.pdf) described in Hyndman & Koehler (2006) I have calculated the absolute error scores for each participant per condition as well as the absolute naive error scores. My question is: in order to generate a MASE score per participant per condition, do I divide the absolute error scores by the average absolute naive error for each participant or the total average absolute naive error across all observations?

I have added an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ekOXznt5HiJ-Dnz3NM2mWajGiyHkySpfHBYpGH0TkHw/edit?usp=sharing) which clearly shows the difference in calculations when looking at the formulas.